# Did I calculate this (simple) integral correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Given the contour $C$:

[image]

we are asked to calculate $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{ze^{z^2-4z}}{z^2-1}dz$. I wrote it as such:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{ze^{z^2-4z}}{z-1}dz+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{ze^{z^2-4z}}{z+1}dz\right)$$ and got that it equals $$\frac{1}{2}N(C,1)e^{-3}-\frac{1}{2}N(C,-1)e^5=e^{-3}+e^{5}$$

Does this look correct? I'm a little shaky on whether I got the indexes right, and some of my friends got that it should equal $0.5(e^{-3}+e^{5})$ instead.

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{z^2-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left( \dfrac{1}{z-1}-\dfrac{1}{z+1}\right)$

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the picture, it seems that the winding numbers are indeed $+2$ (at $1$), and $-2$ (at $-1$), and the rest of your calculations seem to be correct as well.